# What is emacs keybinding s-u?

Tags: emacs

When I run revert-buffer in emacs it says:

```
You can run the command `revert-buffer' with s-u
```

I've never seen any keybinding beginning with s- before.  What key is that?

My emacs version is GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.29) of 2010-05-08 on black.local

Update: Now I see why I didn't understand `s-u`.  It is something added by aquaemacs.  The first thing I did after installing aquaemacs was `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)` to make it work the way I expect.

Comment: Re update, I never installed aquaemacs on my mac.  I use plain emacs 25.* with no gui, yet I get the s-u.  I tried "command-u", all I get is a bell sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the [Super Key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html%5Fnode/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html), similar to `Meta`. More information in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354469/what-does-s-keyname-refer-to-in-emacs-and-how-do-i-tell-emacs-to-ignore-it/1354474#1354474).

Comment: By default, Emac's super key is bound to apple's Command key on for emacs built with the NS or NextStep option. At least that was the case on my copy.